# Bundle Name Changes

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm about to update my iOS app.

Previously it was called

> GCSE Maths - Get A Better Grade

now it I have named my Xcode Project

> The GCSE Maths App

and will upload this onto iTune Connect - is it OK to do this so long as they both have the same bundle identifier?

My worry is it will get rejected for having a different name.

Thanks!

Nci

Comment: "The GCSE Maths App" makes it sound like the official app of the Dept. for Education.  I wouldn't be surprised if your app is pulled sometime down the road...

Answer (score 1):

No, App store will not reject your app, it is fine totally.

Bundle name can be change as you are updating new version. You can not change bundle identifier and application name. App store allows you to change the Display Name(Name just below the App Icon at app list in device).

Answer (score 1):

If apple allowed to change `Display Name` while uploading new binary that means they haven't  any issue. if they have issue then they wan't provide any option to change `Display Name`. if you used same `bundle identifier` then it will overwrite the app on iTunes Connect.